# What happened to pocket remotes for non-SLR cameras?

Tags: point-and-shoot, remote, shutter-release

Why not offer a remote on-less-than-SLR cameras, video or still?

10 years ago, we traveled Europe with my wife handling her pocket 35mm film Minolta Freedom zoom 125, about the size of a pack of cigarettes.... *with remote!* We would often prop the camera on a rock or tree with a six-inch flex tri-pod, and use the remote for outstanding photos.... in 35mm. Now, we are advanced to digital, but, alas, no remote. Why?

Comment: To make you consider buying an SLR?

Answer (score 4):

Luckily, you are wrong. **There are plenty of non-DSLRs with remotes**, either wired or infrared red.

Search for [cameras with infrared remotes](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?remoteinfrared=1) and look at the breakdown by size on the left. As of today, their are [4 ultra-compacts](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?remoteinfrared=1&size=ultracompact), [7 compacts](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?remoteinfrared=1&size=compact) and [7 SLDs](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?remoteinfrared=1&size=sld). Do the same for [cameras with wired remotes](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?remotewired=1) and you will see the smallest is the [Olympus ZX-1](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/olympus/xz1) among a number of larger options.